# How to find where two columns have bigger difference/ are outliers python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, outliers

I have these two arrays:
(two random example arrays created)

```
x = [5,12,24,44,22,32,22]
y = [8,14,26,47,44,35,23]
```

These two columns are related and x[4] and y[4] are the outliers from this data

How would I go through a data frame and return the columns or column numbers which have the outliers in it?

Edit:
Aplogoies. Here is the data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y':y})
```

Comment: In this case you "outliers" are merely the maximum values in each list. Is that what you mean? Perhaps it's more complicated than that. Also, you'll need to load these lists into a dataframe if that's really what you need

Comment: You're mentioning a DataFrame but you're showing lists, please provide the real input. Also what is the criterion to mark a column as outlier? Finally, can you provide the expected output?

Comment: @BrutusForcus - none of them are the maximum. *22* seems to be near the mean of the column, which is an unusual outlier

Comment: @BrutusForcus at x[4] we can see that this is abnormally different to y[4]. So I would want to be the column that is outputted.

Comment: How do you quantify "abnormal"?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I miscounted the offsets. I'm still none the wiser though

Comment: @BrutusForcus Thats what I am having difficulty defining. Bigger difference than normal if that makes any sense?

Comment: What is normal?

Comment: @BrutusForcus When the x and y values are close to each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not **one** method of outlier removal, but dozens.

I would say that given the linear relationship between x and y, it might be ideal to first plot the data and then decide rationally on how to remove the outliers

Here the relationship is clearly linear. I used a robust linear regression with [`scipy.stats.siegelslopes`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.siegelslopes.html) to get the robust fit line.

I plotted to kinds of outlier removal methods. ±10% of the fitted slope and ±10 times the median difference. In comparison the (valid) method proposed by @MichaelSzczesny would be equivalent to the one on the right with a threshold of ~15 (I used 6).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import siegelslopes

f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

xs = np.arange(0, 50)
slope, intercept = siegelslopes(df['y'], df['x'])
ax1.plot(xs, slope*xs+intercept, ls='--')
ax2.plot(xs, slope*xs+intercept, ls='--')

### variation of slope

# keep points with slope variation < 10%
df1 = df[np.log10(df['y']/(df['x']*slope+intercept)).lt(0.1)]
df1.plot.scatter('x', 'y', c='k', ax=ax1)

# plot ± 10%
ax1.plot(xs, slope*1.1*xs+intercept, c='grey', ls=':')
ax1.plot(xs, slope*0.9*xs+intercept, c='grey', ls=':')

# plot outliers
df.drop(df1.index).plot.scatter('x', 'y', c='r', ax=ax1)

ax1.set_ylim(ymin=0)
ax1.set_xlim(xmin=0

### keep points with intercept variation ± 10 * median x-y difference

d = abs(df['y']-(df['x']*slope+intercept))
thresh = d.median()*10
df1 = df[d.lt(thresh)]
df1.plot.scatter('x', 'y', c='k', ax=ax2)

# plot ± threshold
ax2.plot(xs, slope*xs+intercept+thresh, c='grey', ls=':')
ax2.plot(xs, slope*xs+intercept-thresh, c='grey', ls=':')

# plot outliers
df.drop(df1.index).plot.scatter('x', 'y', c='r', ax=ax2)

ax2.set_ylim(ymin=0)
ax2.set_xlim(xmin=0)
```

[image: outlier removal]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is too simplistic but seems to fulfil the brief:-

```
x = [5,12,24,44,22,32,22]
y = [8,14,26,47,44,35,23]
d = [abs(_x - _y) for _x, _y in zip(x, y)]
i = d.index(max(d))
print(x[i], y[i])
```

Comment: What does the underscore do, when I use it, it says that the column is not found?

Comment: Try copy and paste. The leading underscore has no special meaning although my personal preference is to use it to indicate temporary variables (outside of a class context where it can be used conventionally to indicate a "private" member)